Using autoconfig / firefox.cfg with Firefox snap on Ubuntu 22.04
I am using Ubuntu 22.04, which now comes with Firefox as a snap rather than an apt package. As I'm creating an ansible-automated configuration to install software on many machines, I want to configure the homepage for Firefox and change it from the default.
The previously recommended way to do this ref https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-autoconfig was using autoconfig.js in /usr/lib/firefox/defaults/pref with the following content:
pref("general.config.filename", "firefox.cfg");
pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);
pref("general.config.sandbox_enabled", false);

...then, one would create firefox.cfg at /usr/lib/firefox/firefox.cfg with e.g. the following:
var {classes:Cc,interfaces:Ci,utils:Cu} = Components;  
  
/* set new tab page */  
try {  
    Cu.import("resource:///modules/AboutNewTab.jsm");  
    var newTabURL = "https://example.com/";  
    AboutNewTab.newTabURL = newTabURL;
    
    aboutNewTabService = Cc["@mozilla.org/browser/aboutnewtab-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIAboutNewTabService);
    aboutNewTabService.newTabURL = newTabURL;
} catch(e){Cu.reportError(e);} // report errors in the Browser Console  

....but since the introduction of the snap version of Firefox instead, this method does not work.
I saw https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/firefox-snap-no-longer-reads-usr-lib-firefox-for-customization/29713, which suggests /etc/firefox or /var/snap/firefox/current, but trying these results in no success. This includes the following paths:
<dir>/firefox.cfg
<dir>/defaults/firefox.cfg
<dir>/pref/autoconfig.js
<dir>/defaults/pref/autoconfig.js

....and all permutations of these and the aforementioned directories have been tried to no success.
How can I configure the Firefox snap using autoconfig.js and firefox.cfg?
